# How can I hide the reaction text on mobile after provide the reaction

Tags: javascript, css

I am using simple facebook like and comments system. You can see it here: http://creativeartbd.com/demo/facebook/

```
Username : shibbirbd
password : 123456
```

Now, check this site on mobile or using your browser on mobile mode. After that click on post or comment reaction / like. It will show a list of reaction.

Now if you click on any reaction then you can see that reaction text is visible. I need to click again to hide that reaction text.

is there any workaround to hide that reaction text once I have given the reaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `success` callback of the `send-reaction.php` AJAX request, you need to add `$("#"+x).hide();` before you call `$('#login-registraion-btn').modal('show');`.

---

A full example of the `success` `callback`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "send-reaction.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function() {},
  success: function(html) {
    if (parseInt(html) == 1) {
      $("#like" + posts_id).html(htmlData).removeClass("reaction").removeClass("tooltipstered").addClass("unLike").attr("rel", "unlike");
      $("#" + x).hide();
      //refresh();
    } else if (html == 3) {
      $(".like_result").html(html);
      $("#login-registraion-btn").modal("show");

      // THESE TWO NEW LINES
      $("#" + x).hide();
      $(".tipsy").hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @creativeartbd No worries, I've edited my answer up above. Add `$(".tipsy").hide();` around the same line.

Comment: Maybe still it's showing the reaction text after given the reaction.